# Android / PHP: Login successful but Failed redirect to the next activity

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I'm new in android programming. Currently, I develop apps that require login. For now, the login is successful. Below is the code:

MainActivity.JAVA

```
private void userLogin() {
    //first getting the values
    final String badgeid = etBadgeid.getText().toString();
    final String pwd = etPassword.getText().toString();

    //validating inputs
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(badgeid)) {
        etBadgeid.setError("Please enter your badgeid");
        etBadgeid.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pwd)) {
        etPassword.setError("Please enter your password");
        etPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //if everything is fine
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.i("onPostExecute","response is: "+response);

                    try {
                        //converting response to json object
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                        //if no error in response
                        if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //getting the user from the response
                            JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                            //creating a new user object
                            User user = new User(
                                    userJson.getString("badgeid"),
                                    userJson.getString("email"),
                                    userJson.getString("fullname"),
                                    userJson.getInt("roles_id"),
                                    userJson.getInt("team_id")
                            );

                            //storing the user in shared preferences
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                            //starting the profile activity
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("badgeid", badgeid);
            params.put("pwd", pwd);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

URL_LOGIN (PHP)

```
<?php 

    require_once '../config/configPDO.php';

    $response = array();

        if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('badgeid', 'pwd'))){

            $badgeid = $_POST['badgeid'];
            $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT badgeid, email, fullname, roles_id, team_id FROM ot_users WHERE badgeid = :badgeid AND pwd = :pwd AND roles_id = 7 AND team_id <> 1");

            $stmt->bindParam(':badgeid',$badgeid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':pwd',$pwd,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if ($result) {

                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['message'] = 'Login successfull'; 
                $response['user'] = $result;  

            }else{
                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['message'] = 'Invalid username or password';
            }
        }

    echo json_encode($response);

    function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){

        foreach($params as $param){
            if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }

?>
```

Then, I want to use web services (url) when retrieving the data from the database. Below is the php code

URL_LOGIN (PHP)

```
<?php 

    require_once '../config/configPDO.php';

    $response = array();

        if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('badgeid', 'pwd'))){

            $badgeid = $_POST['badgeid'];
            $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

            $url = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/ot_displayUser?badgeid=$badgeid&pwd=$pwd";
            $data = file_get_contents($url);
            $json = json_decode($data);
            $result = $json->otUserList;

            if ($result) {

                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['message'] = 'Login successfull'; 
                $response['user'] = $result;  

            }else{
                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['message'] = 'Invalid username or password';
            }
        }

    echo json_encode($response);

    function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){

        foreach($params as $param){
            if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }

?>
```

When I use this code, It will POPUP "Login successful" but it failed to redirect to the next page (Home.JAVA). Can anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: May I know you are getting any crash or something when you start the activity?

Comment: @DipankarBaghel No. Just popup "Login successful". But if I uses the first PHP code above, it also will popup and redirect to the next activity

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `finish()` method before `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class));`. `finish()` is used to remove current activity from stack. You alway s have to call after navigating to another activty.

If you find this as a correct answer then correct it.

**UPDATED your code so copy the following code:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void userLogin() {
    //first getting the values
    final String badgeid = etBadgeid.getText().toString();
    final String pwd = etPassword.getText().toString();

    //validating inputs
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(badgeid)) {
        etBadgeid.setError("Please enter your badgeid");
        etBadgeid.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pwd)) {
        etPassword.setError("Please enter your password");
        etPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //if everything is fine
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.i("onPostExecute","response is: "+response);

                    try {
                        //converting response to json object
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                        //if no error in response
                        if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //getting the user from the response
                            JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                            //creating a new user object
                            User user = new User(
                                    userJson.getString("badgeid"),
                                    userJson.getString("email"),
                                    userJson.getString("fullname"),
                                    userJson.getInt("roles_id"),
                                    userJson.getInt("team_id")
                            );

                            //storing the user in shared preferences
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                            //starting the profile activity

                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class));
                            finish();  //it will remove current activity from activity stack
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("badgeid", badgeid);
            params.put("pwd", pwd);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer bro. I also received same answer yesterday. but he delete back.